# Geodesic line with endpoints in interior of Riemannian manifold or Alexandrov space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below and non-empty boundary.  Let $\gamma$ be a shortest geodesic  path in $X$ whose endpoints belong to the interior of $X$.

> Is it true that $\gamma$ is contained in the interior of $X$? Is that true at least under the assumption that $X$ is smooth Riemannian manifold with smooth boundary (thus $X$ must be locally geodesically convex)?

Comment: The case when $X$ is a smooth compact domain in a Riemannian manifold follows from elementary arguments once you know that $X$ is geodesically convex (which follows from the assumption that $X$ is an Alexandrov space as I mention in the comments to Michor's answer). Namely, if $[x,y]$ is a segment in $X$ with $x,y$ in the interior, then the segments from $x$ to points of a small neighborhood of $y$ fill a neighborhood of $(x,y)$, and  since by convexity of $X$ all such segments must lie in $X$, no point of $(x,y)$ lies in $\partial X$.

Answer (score 1):

No: Take a banana shaped domain with smooth boundary in the plane.

Edit: This answer is wrong. I leave it here for the very instructive comments by Igor Belegradek.

I think I see geodesic triangles near the concave boundary in the banana where Gauss-Bonet implies large negative curvature.

Comment: The banana is not an Alexandrov space.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Why is the banana not an Alexandrov space? It seems to me that by compactness, Toponogov's theorem should hold possibly with a very very negative lower  curvature bound.

Comment: @Sak: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223934/when-a-riemannian-manifold-with-boundary-is-an-alexandrov-space.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek wow, the more you know! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this. I will delete the answer soon.

Comment: @PeterMichor: please keep it. It is instructive. I even upvoted it. :)

Comment: I wish to add that a smooth compact domain in a Riemannian manifold must be convex if the intrinsic metric on the domain is $CD(K,\infty)$, see Theorem 1.5 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00942. This applies to every finite-dimensional Alexandrov space by https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5948.