# When Riemannian manifold with boundary is Alexandrov space?

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

I am looking for a proof or, better, a reference to a proof of the following known fact.

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold with boundary. Assume the sectional curvature of $M$ is at least $\kappa$.  Then if $M$ is an Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below then it is locally geodesically convex, namely any shortest path between any two sufficiently close points is a geodesic in $M$.

Comment: In Alexandrov geometry any shortest path is a geodesic by definition. Are you using a Riemannian definition of a geodesic (as the solution to a certain ODE)?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Does the usual proof that a shortest path is a geodesic (in a manifold without boundary) fail? Where?

Comment: Manifolds with boundary which are not Alexandrov spaces do not have to be locally geodesically convex because shortest path might be contained in the boundary and thus be a geodesic there rather then in the manifold. Probably more general situation is possible: shortest path might consist of many pieces of geodesics on the manifold and on its boundary.

Comment: Why don't the references I gave in your other question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365457/geodesic-line-with-endpoints-in-interior-of-riemannian-manifold-or-alexandrov-sp provide an answer? All you need to do is to embed $M$ into a complete Riemannian manifold of the same dimension and apply theorem 1.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00942. For example, double $M$ along the boundary and extend the Riemannian metric on $M$ to a Riemannian metric on the double.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: Oops. I missed that your comment. Sorry about that. But anyway the argument seems to be very indirect and in much greater generality I need at the moment. I would prefer something more elementary.